# Crowd sourcing polygons on Google Maps?

Tags: polygon, google-maps, software-recommendations, crowdsourcing

Looking for a way to crowd-source polygon creation on Google Maps (in a wiki environment) that doesn't involved ESRI's expensive server software.

Requirements:

- a bunch of different wiki pages can be updated with a map showing a single polygon.
- all the polygons over the entire site are combined into one master map
- preferably everything in KML so Fusion Tables can be involved for styling, but not necessary

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend taking a look at [CartoDB](http://cartodb.com). It basically provides a hosted instance of PostgreSQL, and sports a fairly easy to use API. I've seen it combined nicely with the Google Maps API [Drawing Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#drawing_tools) (see [this](http://developers.cartodb.com/examples/editing-polygons.html) for an example)

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenLayers, Geoserver and PostgreSQL to build a application like this.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://ooze.me/. It provides a process and method for crowdsourcing vectorized GIS data from overhead imagery.

Comment: It looks like it would require ugly hacks to integrate into a web site (supports only manual downloading?). Anyway, the OP wasn't clear if the wiki would be just a dumping ground or an integral part of an ongoing process, but it may well be an insurmountable burden for this piece of software.

Comment: I'm not looking to pay people to crowd-source the information which ooze seems to be.  The information would come from users of the site and their personal knowledge.